# Leaflet JS getBound to TileLayer

Tags: leaflet

I have a web site to displaying historic maps. The maps have been tiled and are loaded as a tilelayer. Is there a way to getBound so I can set the map with fitBound. By default tilelayer does not have a getBounds method. I have tried making a featureGroup of the layer but that just raises an error. Am I missing something? Thanks.

```
// Initiate map
var map = new L.Map('map', {minZoom: 8, maxZoom: 18, zoom: 10}); 

// Display and set boundary
var layer = new L.TileLayer('../../maps/1866/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{maxNativeZoom: 17});

//create featuregroup
var fgroup = new L.featureGroup([layer]);
fgroup.addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(fgroup.getBounds());
```

Comment: You'll have to fetch the metadata from the original dataset (i.e. the untiled raster files) and somehow make that available to the frontend.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I thought that may be the only solution. I'll extract the information from the original raster files. All the best for 2022 :)